# Thread interaction scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

[image]

Hello,

I am a newbie in multithreading and would like to know how thread interaction works in the below scenario(PFA diagram). Method 1 is synchronized on Object 1, method 2 is synchronized on Object 2 and method 3 is synchronized on both Object 1 and 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java if you have synchronized methods, they are only synchronized on a single object; that is the object instance `this`, if it is an instance method or the `Class` object if it is a static method.

Technically what you say can be implemented like this, using classical synchronization:

```
public static MyClass {
    private final FIRST_LOCK = new Object();
    private final SECOND_LOCK = new Object();

    public void m1() {
        synchronized(FIRST_LOCK) {
        } 
    }

    public void m2() {
        synchronized(SECOND_LOCK) {    
        } 
    }

    public void m3() {
        synchronized(FIRST_LOCK) {
            synchronized(SECOND_LOCK) {
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

What this is means is if method `m1` or `m2` are executed by a thread, then other threads cannot execute `m3` and the other way round - if some threads execute `m3` then no other threads can execute `m1` or `m2`.